# How to disable 'save' option in Excel but 'save as' should be still working

Tags: vba, excel

I need to disable the save option in Excel but I still need the save as option to be working... So I know how to disable both of the option by this VBA:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
    Cancel = True    
End Sub
```

But How is it possible to disable save but save us to be working still.
Thank you for helping me

Comment: Use `Cancel = True` then open a SaveAs dialog. If the returned name (path ...?) is the same as the original, discard it. If they are not the same, save it. Might have to have a public boolean that evades overlapping.

Comment: I like it. How the VBA should look like. Thanks

Comment: couldn't you actually change that in the options of word? (if you want to do it in vba, that's totally ok... just interested... :) )

Comment: I would rather the VBA but you can tell me how to do that as well. Thanks

Comment: You could set a password to the workbook to allow editing. Click SaveAs, click the Tools dropdown and select General Options. Then set a password for modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
 If SaveAsUI = False Then
  MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
  Cancel = True
 End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

To delete the code from `ThisWorkbook` Class Module (delete every thing) we can use this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

 If SaveAsUI = False Then
  MsgBox "You can't save this workbook!"
  Cancel = True

 Else
  With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule
   .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
  End With

 End If
End Sub
```

NOTE:

- This will delete everything in `ThisWorkbook` Class Module not only `Workbook_BeforeSave`
- We must allow *Trust access to the VBA project object model* (File > Options > click Trust Center, click Trust Center Settings, and then click Macro Settings).

Comment: Works perfect but is it possible to work ojly innl tye original ... So when the coppy is saved obce you can edit it becouse now even the coppy is not allowed to be saved ... So is there any way tye original one is the same like it is and the coppy to be exactly the same but without this vba... So after save to delete this lines of code